# Environment variables in clickhouse config

Tags: clickhouse

Can we define separate parts of some tag in clickhouse config with environment variables?

For example we can use:

```
<engine from_env="ENGINE"/>
```

then all the value comes from env variable.

But can we use something like this:

```
<engine>ENGINE = MergeTree PARTITION BY ${PARTITIONING}
        ORDER BY (event_date, event_time)
        TTL ${TTL}
</engine>
```

Or is there some other option for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from_env` for this. Eg:

```
<clickhouse>
<profiles>
    <default>
        <max_query_size from_env="MAX_QUERY_SIZE"/>
    </default>
</profiles>
```

Refer to [Clickhouse doc here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/configuration-files)